# How to reduce the complexity?

Tags: for-loop, complexity-theory, reduce

I have to resolve a problem using dynamic programming.

```
for(int i = 3; i < N; i++){
   for(int j= 3; j < T; j++){
   ..
```

I want to reduce the complexity.How can I make this?

Answer (score 0):

I need to understand what your recursion's base case is.  I think with that information I could turn this into a more efficient looping construct.  But with what I know right now, I would just transcribe your first functional definition into it's logically C# equivalent...

```
int S(int i, int j)
{
    if (?) // the base case, must be at least one, can have more then one.  (e.g. when i=N or j=T)
        return ?; // What gets returned ultimately controls how efficient we can make this.

    var maxValue = S(i-1, j-1);
    for (var k = j-2; k < i-3; k++)
        maxValue = Math.Max( maxValue, S(k, j-3) );
    return maxValue;
}
```

And inside the for loop, we can make things more efficient by doing your own comparison instead of calling to Math.Max.  I used Math.Max simple because it's easier to read, but a simple performance enhancement would be to place the return from S into a temp variable, and then use >?: to set maxValue.